# How to display an image on image source from directly setting the src as api endpoint

Tags: reactjs, rest

I am working on a React app. I have an API having a parameter as a path that returns the stream of an image after download.
I am setting the API endpoint URL in my image src. 
For example: `src = apipath/controller/download?path = path`

It is hitting the API and displaying the image but it’s failing if I am using an authorized API method.

So please suggest how can I make it work with the same URL.
Or if you have any other way to do it

Comment: There's no way to fetch an image from an endpoint that requires authentication without leaking the credentials unless the user is already pre-authenticated and you can rely on an authentication cookie in your image API handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a component to fetch the image from your API
I haven't test this code yet, but I think you can try

```
imports ....

    const MyImage = (props)=> ({
    
// keep image looks beautiful
        const [state, setState] = useState({src: 'nophoto.png'}); 
    
        useEffect(()=> {
 // fetch image from api
            fetch(`apipath/controller/download?path=${props.path}`)
                .then(response => response.blob())
                .then(blob => {
 // convert blob to valid base64 image
                    setState({ src: URL.createObjectURL(blob) })
                })
    
        }, [props.path]) // update at every path changes
    
    
        
            return (
               state.src && (<img alt={props.alt} src={state.src} />)

            )

    }) 
    
    export default MyImage ;


usage:

import MyImage from '...your path'

<MyImage path='helloWorld.png'>
```